# mysql distinct and count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have table like this:

```
+------+-------+
| user | data  |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   a   |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   b   |
+------+-------+
|  2   |   c   |
+------+-------+
```

I need to get something like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

Get unique user and count the instances in data row, any ideas?

I've tried with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user from table ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` for this.

```
SELECT `User`, COUNT(data) TotalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY `User`
ORDER BY TotalCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) from table
GROUP BY user

(not tested)